# Why not stuff all my money into a new high interest savings?

Tags: savings, retirement

I have a well-balanced portfolio.  I am leaving my job for a year.  I see [here](https://www.wsj.com/buyside/personal-finance/five-percent-savings-rates-01673543935?mod=wsj_hp_buyside_pos3) that I can potentially receive 5% on my money.  Is there a reason *not* to take everything out of stocks and bonds and put it in one of these savings accounts until I work again?

Comment: "Everything* is a big, absolute word.

Comment: Working or not working  usually doesn't affect where you keep your money. Not working may mean you have to draw down your investments to pay bills, but that can be done incrementally as needed rather than all or nothing. I think you aren't asking the right question.

Comment: 5% in HYSA is relatively new and probably temporary, whereas stock returns at 5-7% annually are consistent over the last decades. What's your time horizon?

Comment: @littleadv IIRC in 2022 HYSAs and CDs outperformed stocks by a very wide margin of something like 20%. Given the current economic environment, I'd say the performance of stocks is extremely uncertain right now.

Comment: @user253751 what about 2023? Depending on the time horizon

Comment: @littleadv nobody will know until the fat lady sings. And what about 2024? Point is, stocks are pretty volatile lately and maybe not worth dumping your entire life savings into while you are unemployed.

Comment: @user253751 not disagreeing necessarily, but that's an opinion, hence my vote to close

Answer (score 4):

> I have a well-balanced portfolio. I am leaving my job for a year. I
> see here that I can potentially receive 5% on my money

By well balanced I assume that you have diversification, and that some money is for near term things, and some for longer term thins like a house or retirement.

Because you know (or suspect) that you will be unemployed for a year (or so), that means you should be able to calculate what expenses you will have, and what income from non-working sources you will have.

> Is there a reason not to take everything out of stocks and bonds and
> put it in one of these savings accounts until I work again?

- If you have $1,000,000 in stocks, but only need $50,000 to live for a year; that would mean you are moving a ton of value out of the market when you don't have to.
- Selling shares could trigger a massive tax bill.
- Moving money within a IRA or 401(k) or similar account would not cause a tax issue, but can you get a 5% rate withing those types of accounts? You might be able to change broker without changing the color of the money to get to the type of account you need.
- Unless you are talking about a CD that locks in the rate for a period of time, or some other type of account, the rate could change tomorrow. Using a CD will lock in the rate, but will also tie up the money.

Comment: Even if you only have $100,000 in stocks, it'll generate a (relatively) big tax bill.

Answer (score 3):

To me, the question as written, only begs for more data:

- How much is "everything"?
- How much is in qualified plans as opposed to taxable accounts?
- Why is 5% a return on your money a desirable goal?
- What money do you plan to live on during that time?
- Why do you feel that you can only be invested in stocks while working?

The higher interest rates provide an interesting opportunity for those close to retirement.  Many, myself included, have been doing retirement planning with their portfolio returning between 3 and 4 percent.  Right now one can purchase long term bonds (over 20 year maturity) that are earning over 4.5%.

To me, that is very attractive, and I have moved some money in that direction.  As I move closer to retirement date, I will move more assets to those that produce income which includes dividend payers and bonds.  However a large portion of my savings will always be in stocks given their traditional 10% ROI.

In your own situation I would be tempted to construct a CD ladder with a large portion of the money you needed to live for a year.  If you needed 40K to live, I would put about 10K maturing in about 9 months, 10K in 6, and 10K in 3.  Using brokered CDs is a way to achieve this.